# creating a pip repository from already installed package - error setup.py not found

Tags: python, django, pip

I have a package installed in my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package-name , its our private repo installed at that place long back and that pip repo not available now ,  so can I use that particular /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package-name directory to install anywhere else ? This is what I have done:

zipped the directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package-name
Upload to my server
Then tried to install using pip like this : pip install myserverpackageurl

Then i got error saying that "setup.py" is not available (IOError) .

I also tried creating a bundle from my directory like this :

```
  cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package-name
  pip bundle package-name package-name
```

then again i got the error :

```
 ("Directory %r is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.", 'mm/')
 Storing complete log in /home/bhaskar/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: exactly what I tried to do:/ too bad it's does not look like possible

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just zip up a installed package; it doesn't include the `setup.py` file needed by tools like `pip` to install the a python package and ensure the installation is correct and complete.

Pip only works with source distributions; you usually create such a distribution by running the `sdist` command on the existing `setup.py` file:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

The most recent pip version also supports python eggs, but you'll still need the `setup.py` file to create those.

Comment: And what about those kind of programs like [peepdf](https://github.com/jesparza/peepdf) that doesn't have `setup.py` ?

Comment: @yucer: ask them to create one? That project is not installable with standard Python tools without one.